# passing static reflection information to static generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

EDIT: the class/method  that i'm trying to run this inside is static and therefore i'm unable to pass this into the generic.Invoke

I have a static Data Access Class that i use to automatically parse data from various sources.
i was starting to re-factor it when i ran into a problem.
Im tring to pass a Type to a Generic method via reflection,
(the method then parses the type and returns the Type with a value)
my code currently looks like

```
Type type1 = typeof( T );
var item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( T ), new object[] { } );

foreach (PropertyInfo info in type1.GetProperties())
{
    Type dataType = info.PropertyType;
    Type dataType = info.PropertyType;
    MethodInfo method = typeof( DataReader ).GetMethod( "Read" );
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod( dataType ); 
    //The next line is causing and error as it expects a 'this' to be passed to it
    //but i cannot as i'm inside a static class
    generic.Invoke( this, info.Name, reader );
    info.SetValue(item,DataReader.Read<dataType>(info.Name, reader ) , null);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `DataReader.Read` is the static method, right?

Therefore, change the error line like below, since you are calling the static method. There is not object, so you just pass `null` into `Invoke` method:

```
var value = generic.Invoke( null, new object[] {info.Name, reader} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter to a generic method isn't an instance of `Type`; you can't use your variable in this way.  However, you can use reflection to create the closed-generic `MethodInfo` you require (that is, with the type parameter specified), which would look something like this:

```
// this line may need adjusting depending on whether the method you're calling is static
MethodInfo readMethod = typeof(DataReader).GetMethod("Read"); 

foreach (PropertyInfo info in type1.GetProperties())
{
    // get a "closed" instance of the generic method using the required type
    MethodInfo genericReadMethod m.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { info.PropertyType });

    // invoke the generic method
    object value = genericReadMethod.Invoke(info.Name, reader);

    info.SetValue(item, value, null);
}
```